# PHP using $_GET to get a URL with variables in it

Tags: php

I'm using PHP $_GET to get a URL from a URL variable like so:

```
echo 'URL: ' . $_GET['url'];
```

When I get a regular URL it echos fine, for example:

```
http://localhost?url=http://google.com
```

The output is:

```
URL: http://google.com
```

But if the URL contains multiple variables, they get cut off, for example:

```
http://localhost?url=http://google.com?id1=55&id2=88&id3=99
```

Will return:

```
URL: http://google.com?id1=55
```

If there any way around this so I can get the URL regardless of what it contains? e.g. so it returns:

```
URL: http://google.com?id1=55&id2=88&id3=99
```

Updated, in response to Yuu:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$parse = parse_url($url);

$replace_old = array($parse['host'],'http://');
$replace_new = array("","");

$url_vars = str_replace($replace_old,$replace_new,$url);

echo $parse['host'] . htmlentities($url_vars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to urlencode your URL, in order to parse the special characters.

```
<?php
$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
echo '<a href="http://google.com?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Edit as response to edit:

This would work. You needed to encode the `&` right at the `GET` stage.

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];
unset($_GET['url']);
if ($_GET) {
    $url .= '&' . http_build_query($_GET);
}
$parse = parse_url($url);


$replace_old = array($parse['host'],'http://');
$replace_new = array("","");

$url_vars = str_replace($replace_old,$replace_new,$url);


echo $parse['host'] . $url_vars;


?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as far as I can see, this unfortunately does not work when the URL is retrieved from a URL using $_GET, because the other variables cannot be retrieved from the URL at all (see code posted above)

Comment: @TheBobster You need to urlencode the `&` symbol to `%26`. It should work with that.

Comment: @TheBobster I have edited my answer with the code, please check if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `urlencode` first the `url` value before passing it.

Example:

```
echo urlencode('http://google.com?id1=55&id2=88&id3=99');
```

Output:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%3Fid1%3D55%26id2%3D88%26id3%3D99
```

And in your URL

```
http://localhost?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%3Fid1%3D55%26id2%3D88%26id3%3D99
```